# Multiply Numpy n x 2 array by n x 1 array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

Assuming I have a Numpy n x 2 array `y`: `array([[1, 1], [2, 3], [1, 4], ...])` and a Numpy n x 1 array `x`: `array([2, 4, 5, ...])`, how can I efficiently obtain the following result, n x 2 array: `array([2, 2], [8, 12], [5, 20], ...])`, where each element (array) of the `y` is multiplied by corresponding value from array `x`?

I can do it via a cycle but looking for more performant approaches.

Comment: Sounds like you're just looking for `x * y`.

Comment: You are right! I did not reshape my arrays correctly, so the `*` was not working. Thank you! Please submit this as an answer.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, that `x` isn't n by 1. It's n-not-by-anything.

Comment: `x[:,None]*y` - [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an actual n-by-1 `x`, you could just do `x * y`. Your `x` is 1-dimensional, n-not-by-anything, so you'd have to reshape it first:

```
x.reshape((n, 1)) * y
```

Comment: This may seem like a working solution in terms of programming, but in terms of linear algebra, and a series of multiplications, it will turn very confusing and hard to follow.
In other words, someone who doesn't no anything about linear algebra may accept this as a solution, but in practice, this is far from ideal.

Comment: @Ash: That honestly just sounds like something that'll go away as you get more used to NumPy. Reshaping and broadcasting like this is very common in NumPy code.